How to remove branch name from files downloaded from github
I have a repository on github for a mod for a game, some of the contained files are config files, which need to be at a very specific file path to work properly.
When you download from the repository (code > download zip) the downloaded file is called reponame-main.zip how do i make it so that the branch name (-main) is not added to the end?


Git is not a very good deployment tool. Consider using a different mechanism.


Would you provide a link to the repository? 2) Is your intention that they can simply unzip and drop the resulting folder where their config files should be?


A1: https://github.com/ZZetho/TU_ExtraDockingPorts  A2: yes

I don't believe Github lets you do that. You could possibly add it as a binary file to your release.
You can change your repository layout so the necessary configuration folder is inside the repository. Then tell you users to unzip and copy the internal folder to their config.
License.txt
README.md
TU_ExtraDockingPorts/
  Textures/
  Default/
  TU_EDP_Default.cfg
  ...

When they unzip TU_ExtraDockingPorts-main.zip they'll get...
TU_ExtraDockingPorts-main/
  License.txt
  README.md
  TU_ExtraDockingPorts/
    Textures/
    Default/
    TU_EDP_Default.cfg
    ...

Tell them to copy TU_ExtraDockingPorts/ into gamedata.

When you download a repository as a zip, it converts the name. This is normal. Have you tried renaming the file? Try to just simply remove the "-main"

yes that does work but i would like it so that people dont have to do that

Make a script to do it for you.
